# Is it possible to include c code in python in pycharm?

Tags: python, c, pycharm

I'm trying to speed up some code that I have written in Python and have thought about writing some code in C to do so. However, I am using PyCharm and its supported languages section,
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/supported-languages.html doesn't mention C, meaning no option to just create a C file and then import it into python. Is there any other way of doing it?

Comment: you need CLion (which it has basic support also for Python). Or just normal terminal tools (and PyCharm editor) if you have simple project

Comment: Of course you can create a file, rename it to *.c and keep it in your project. PyCharm will be fine with opening that file for you, with C syntax highlighting. No support for C just means that it will not index your C code, it will not have options like "Go to definition" of a variable in C. But working with both Python and C within single project works without issues.

Comment: Installing CLion for just 1 or 2 files in C looks like an overkill.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately PyCharm does not support any C/C++ coding and there are no existing plugins for PyCharm that will support this. With that said, there is an IDE for C and C++ called **CLion** which is released by JetBrains just like PyCharm. CLion supports many features varying from Python debugger to Python Console for working with python and also supports all features that Pycharm offers. This should satisfy your needs towards using C code with Python in the most healthy way.

Here are some useful links for you:

https://www.jetbrains.com/clion/

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/python.html#features

Good luck!